# How to use RxJs in Firefox Addon development?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, reactive-programming, rxjs

Follow the steps described in this [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Using_third-party_modules_%28jpm%29), I use the following command to install `rxjs`:

```
npm install @reactivex/rxjs --save
```

then I write the testing code below in my `index.js` file:

```
'use strict';
var Rx = require('@reactivex/rxjs');
Rx.Observable.from('test').subscribe(function (c) { return console.log(c); });
```

When I ran:

```
jpm run
```

I got these errors from the terminal:

```
JPM [error]   Message: TypeError: root_1.root.Symbol is undefined
  Stack:
    @resource://xxxx/node_modules/@reactivex/rxjs/dist/cjs/util/Symbol_observable.js:5:5
@resource://xxxx/node_modules/@reactivex/rxjs/dist/cjs/Observable.js:3:27
@resource://xxxx/node_modules/@reactivex/rxjs/dist/cjs/Rx.KitchenSink.js:1:20
@resource://xxxx/node_modules/@reactivex/rxjs/index.js:1:18
@resource://xxxx/index.js:2:10
run@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/runner.js:147:19
startup/</<@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/runner.js:87:9
Handler.prototype.process@resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:934:23
this.PromiseWalker.walkerLoop@resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:813:7
this.PromiseWalker.scheduleWalkerLoop/<@resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:747:1
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used RxJS myself but I have been wanting to learn it.

Here are some addons out there that do use it:

- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/wappalyzer/
- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/keypocket/
- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/qtest-web-explorer/ - uses rx.lite

I would love to see how you use it

Comment: Thank you for the information! I have a look at the third one's source code, seems it just use `rx` in the scripts that running in embedded pages(so called `page script`). But I want to use `rx` in the content scripts

Comment: I'm a newbie in Firefox Addon development, qtest-web-explorer's folder structure is so different to the one I'm writing which based on Add-on SDK.

Comment: @wenLiangcan KeyPocket is a pure SDK addon, check that out :)